# ubuntu upgrade from 14 LTS to 15.04

Tags: 15.04

Can I upgrade from 14 LTS to 15 without formatting ubuntu 14.

I currently have Win 7 and 14 LTS as dual boot. I don't want to mess things up cuz of the grub menu.

Comment: Yes, 14.04 LTS -> 14.10 -> 15.04. Not sure why, but good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command
`sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

or try this

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Comment: -1 This won't upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04.